# A geometry problem related to circumcenter.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

If a, b and c are the lengths of the sides of a triangle ABC and if $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ are the lengths of the perpendiculars drawn from the circumcenter onto the sides BC, CA and AB respectively, then show that

$$\dfrac{a}{p_1} + \dfrac{b}{p_2} + \dfrac{c}{p_3}= \dfrac{abc}{4p_1 p_2 p_3}$$

I have done some bashing but I am unable to arrive at the final result. This problem is of 10+2 level as well.

Comment: Here is a [quick Mathjax reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). :)

Comment: Can anyone edit it

Comment: It is editted....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know

$ a=2R\sin A, b=2R\sin B, c=2R\sin C $

and

$ p_1=R\cos A, p_2=R\cos B, p_3=R\cos C $

This can be seen on a diagram of a triangle and its circumcircle. From the right triangles and little angle chasing we get these.

Comment: I have done up-to this.... The angle chasing gets me caught.....

Comment: Do you know in any triangle tan A + tan B + tan C = tan A tan B tan C because A+B+C=180?

Comment: Yes... I am aware of that

Comment: Then direct substitution gives the result.

Comment: Anything more you would like to say.... I mean how to complete the problem

Comment: OK... OK.. I got it

Comment: If this was useful, you can upvote and accept.

Comment: Very useful... Anand

Comment: As.... My reputation is less than 15,I couldnot invite... But I have accepted